# What are the good study materials on Association Rules?

Tags: machine-learning, python, references, numpy, association-rules

I am looking to learn Association Rules, from basic level.
I was looking for some good web based materials to start with.
My objectives in the materials is to:

(a) learn the aspect nicely from basic;

(b) work out sample problems;

(c) execute at least one project preferably in Python.

I tried to search Internet but found many links.
I am looking for some good and reliable yet easy to learn source.

I thought to discuss the issue over here in the room of esteemed people.

If anyone may kindly guide me.

Answer (score 1):

[Coursera course: Pattern Discovery in Data Mining](https://www.coursera.org/course/patterndiscovery) is a very good source for this and its opening is talking about association mining.

It seems that `scikit-learn` hasn't had codes completed for `Apriori` yet but you are able to build your own version with some time learning.

[Apriori](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apriori_algorithm) is a very classic method and it's not difficult, I recommend that you start from here.

I am no expert on this so I am not sure if these will fit your needs.